# Derivatives of Logarithms with respect to time.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

I do economics and we are differentiating the Cobbs Douglas production function with respect to time.

Our lecture slides only show that there is a "mathematical trick" which is taking logs and then derivatives. I'm struggling to understand how to find the derivative with respect to time. Our lecture slides show

$$k = \frac {K}{L} \implies \log k = \log K - \log L \text{ (I understand up to here) } \implies \frac{\dot{k}}{k} = \frac{\dot{K}}{K} = \frac{\dot{L}}{L}$$

as well as
$$y=k^{a} = \frac{\dot{y}}{y} = a\frac{\dot{k}}{k}.$$

I think I understand taking the derivatives of logs but I'm stumped on how to take it with respect to time in this case. I am also confused on how you would write this out in order to explain how you get to the end product.

If anyone can help that would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: If you don't take the derivative with respect to time what *do* you take it with respect to.  Wheres the variables in the equation.  What is $k, K$ and $L$.  Are they all constants?  If they aren't constants whats the variable and how are they measured.  If they are constants you can't take the derivative.  And what is the "Cobbs Douglas production function"? Don't assume because you have declared yourself a novice in math, that you aren't also the local expert in economics (or which many of us probably know nothing).

Comment: Presumably $K$ and $L$ are both functions with regard to time.  Therefore deriving with respect to time is nothing more or less than deriving them.  And derivatives have to be with respect to *something* and that something is rarely anything other than the input of the function (and when it isn't you use the chain rule).

Comment: Sorry fleablood, I should've explained better.  My understanding is that K & L are both functions with regard to time. K is the total capital and L is the labour force so k is the capital per capita (K/L). . Y is the output of both K & L. y is output per capita (Y/L). They aren't constants as they change over time/depending on the input of a given K and L is my understanding. The Cobbs Douglas function is Y=K^aL^1-a

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand.  $K(t)$ is a function and $L(t)$ is function.  The input variable is time.  You take the derivative in terms of the input variable.  If you call that input variable $x$ or $w$ or time or marzipanbarbapapa it doesn't make any different to how you differentiate.  So why do you think you are having trouble with differentiating with regards to time?

Comment: If $\log k(t) = \log K(t) - \log L(t)$ the using the chain rule and knowing that the derivative of log is the reciprical function, we have $[\log k(t)]' =[\log K(t) -\log L(t)]'$ is $\frac 1{k(t)}\cdot k'(t) = \frac 1{K(t)}\cdot K'(t)-\frac 1{L(t)}L'(t)$.  If $y(t)=k(t)^a$ then $y'(t)= ak(t)^{a-1}k'(t) = ak(t)^a\cdot \frac 1{k(t)}\cdot k'(t)= ak(t)^a\cdot[\frac 1{K(t)}\cdot K'(t)-\frac 1{L(t)}L'(t)]$.

Comment: Still struggling with the last one. We are told to use the same trick again so would it be this? 
${y=k^{a}}= {logy = alogk}$
This is then be $$\frac{1}{y_{(t)}} * y'_{(t)}
= a\frac{1}{k_{(t)}} * k'_{(t)}$$?
This would result in $\frac{1}{y_{(t)}} * \frac{y'_{(t)}*y_{(t)}}{y_{{t}}}  
= \frac{1}{k_{(t)}} * a\frac{k'_{(t)}*k_{(t)}}{k_{{t}}}$ This would then become $\frac{y'_{(t)}*y_{(t)}}{y_{{t}^{2}}} = a\frac{k'_{(t)}*k_{(t)}}{k_{{t}^{2}}}$ which would then become $\frac{1}{y_{(t)}} * \frac{y'_{(t)}}{y_{{t}}} = a\frac{k'_{(t)}}{k_{{t}}}$ Then $\frac{\dot{y}}{y} = a\frac{\dot{k}}{k}$